# Can ‘on the other hand' be used without 'on one hand'?

Tags: word-usage

Do I need to say 'on one hand' first to say 'on the other hand', or I can say 'on the other hand' without saying 'on one hand'?

Can 'on the other hand' be used like 'however'?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the 'one hand'.

> **on the other hand**
>
> in a way that is different from the first thing you mentioned:
>
> *My husband likes classical music – I, on the other hand, like all kinds.*

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on-the-other-hand

Comment: But there is nothing wrong with including "one hand". However if you do, the usual form is "one the one hand,....,however on the other hand...".